# Call function after history.push() redirects

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a function that checks if a user is logged in on componentDidMount and changes the log in button to log out if there is a session.

Problem:

I tried using ComponentdidUpdate but since the component is already mounted and i was not able to update the state, it doesn't refresh, hence my log in button stays as a log in button.

```
componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(config.ServerURL + "/user", {withCredentials: true}).then(result => {
            console.log("component mounted:",result.data)
            if (result.data) {
                this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log({message: error.response});
        })
    }
```

I have a button that changes based on the state: isLoggedIn:

```
<div className={"App-login-button"}>
                                {!this.state.isLoggedIn && <Link to={"/login"}>
                                    <AwesomeButton type="primary" title={"Login"}>Login</AwesomeButton>
                                </Link>}

                                {this.state.isLoggedIn && <Link to={"/logout"}>
                                    <AwesomeButton type="primary" title={"logout"} onPress={this.handleLogOut}>logout</AwesomeButton>
                                </Link>}

                            </div>
```

When I log in from my login component (eg: localhost:3000/login)

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        Axios.post(Config.ServerURL + '/auth/login',
            {email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password},
            {
                withCredentials: true

            }).then(result => {
            if (result.data.business) {
                this.props.history.push({pathname: '/business', state: {email: result.data.email}});
            }
            useHistory.push('/', );

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            //console.log(error.response.data.info)
        });

    }
```

for user

```
exports.find = (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
}
```

I would like to either:

change the state.isLoggedIn to true

or

run a get User check again.

Comment: In your componentDidMount function you are calling an API and when it gives the response you are updating the state. Now when state is updated the render function should be called again, so it should show the desired behaviour.

Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: I log in from a different component page (Login.js)

when I return to my landing page (App.js), my app component does not update from history.push(). Therefore, my button that is displayed from App.js is not updated from the change in login.js

Comment: In your componentDidMount you have called a get api, but where is the user data(like email(something unique)) to check wether this particular user is logged in or not?

Comment: have you tried to run some console.log in your .then method, because your state is not getting updated, or your api is not working properly because of which this problem is happening

Comment: If there is a req.user, the GET call will have object in result.data. Therefore, the state to set as logged in is true. My state is getting updated on first entry of the page. The problem is this road of logic. 

unlogged in: 

(LOGIN BUTTON IS SHOWN).
press LOGIN -> Landing page component routes to login component.
Enter Credentials in LOGIN COMPONENT.
Login component routes to landing page. 
(LOGIN BUTTON IS SHOWN). The LOGIN button is shown instead of LOGOUT button because the landingpage did not run the get function again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
useHistory.push('/');
```

back to

```
this.props.history.push('/');
this.props.history.go();
```

the go forces a refresh on the page, allowing the component to rerender. I don't mind the added computational issue, so this works for me.